# How can I find text for span within span?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor, jasmine

Following is my code:

```
<span id="agText" class="ag-header-cell-text">
    <span style="height: 100%;">Coordinator</span>
</span>
```

I was trying the following:

```
var cordinator = element(by.cssContainingText('#agText > span','Coordinator'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `#agText span`

e.g.

```
var cordinator = element(by.cssContainingText('#agText span','Coordinator'));
```

Comment: KISS principle always.